# IIf statement comparing a calculated value

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a form that user inputs the QTY of an item and then selects a combo box to select the item. The combo box populates the other text boxes.

I have one of the boxes do a calculation. I then have another box take the calculated value and compare it. Based on the comparison I have it populate the box. I have `IIf([Text382]>[Text41],[Text45],[Text43])`.

The issue that I am having is the comparison is not working properly. For example if text382 value was 35 and text41 was 1, it would populate the wrong value in the text box. QTY is 600, unit weight is .015 and limit is 1. The calculation comes out correctly to 9 but it will put 355 instead of 366.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason could be that comboboxes always return text. So convert to numbers:

```
IIf(Val([Text382])>Val([Text41]),[Text45],[Text43])
```

and further:

```
Val(IIf(Val([Text382])>Val([Text41]),[Text45],[Text43]))
```